# How to properly plot on a heatmap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I would like to plot on a heatmap. So far, this is what I have:

**Preparation**

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

f = lambda x, y: 1/(x*y)
f_iso = lambda x: 1 / (.2*x) # iso-line at .2

X = np.linspace(1,10,100)
Y = X
data = np.empty([len(X), len(Y)], dtype=float)

for xx, x in enumerate(X):
    data[xx,:] = [ f(x,y) for y in Y ]
```

**Plotting**

```py
# Wrapper function to translate (x,y)-coordinates to 0,N ranges of heatmaps
coord = lambda x, ref: (x-min(ref)) * (len(ref)-1) / (max(ref)-min(ref)) + .5

fig, ax = plt.subplots( 1, figsize=(12,8) )
sns.heatmap(data=data, ax=ax, robust=True,
           xticklabels=[ '{:.0f}'.format(n) if ii%8==0  else '' for ii, n in enumerate(X) ],
           yticklabels=[ '{:.0f}'.format(n) if ii%8==0  else '' for ii, n in enumerate(Y) ])

ax.invert_yaxis()
_, _ = plt.yticks(rotation=0), plt.xticks(rotation=0)

ax.plot( [ coord(x,X) for x in X ], [ coord(f_iso(x), Y) for x in X ], ls='--', color='white' )

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('plot_normal.jpg', dpi=300)
```

[image: plot]

This is already a mess.

But it gets worse when I try to switch to log-log

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots( 1, figsize=(12,8) )
sns.heatmap(data=data, ax=ax, robust=True,
           xticklabels=[ '{:.0f}'.format(n) if ii%8==0  else '' for ii, n in enumerate(X) ],
           yticklabels=[ '{:.0f}'.format(n) if ii%8==0  else '' for ii, n in enumerate(Y) ])

ax.invert_yaxis()
_, _ = plt.yticks(rotation=0), plt.xticks(rotation=0)

ax.set_xscale('log'), ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlim([0,np.log10(10)])
ax.set_ylim([0,np.log10(10)])

ax.plot( [ coord(x,X) for x in X ], [ coord(f_iso(x), Y) for x in X ], ls='--', color='white' )

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('plot_loglog_after.jpg', dpi=300)
```

[image: loglog_after]

as this is clearly wrong as `f` is a power-law and hence should be linear.

```py
plt.loglog(X, [f_iso(x) for x in X])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('plot_loglog.jpg', dpi=300)
```

[image: loglog_true]

Furthermore, all kinds of bugs arise here:

- Setting the lower limit from 0 to e.g. 1e9: No plot anymore
- Moving the `ax.plot` part in-front of `set_[x/y]scale`: No plot anymore
- [...]

So, how do I *properly* plot on heatmaps (incl. log-log)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62003702/generate-a-loglog-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set

Comment: heatmap adds a wrapper layer to `plt.pcolormesh` that makes it better for plotting dataframes with categorical axes; you are now doing a lot of work to _undo_ that wrapper. It would likely be easier for your usecase to work directly with `plt.pcolormesh`.